# Upload video to youtube using c# winform "Invalid credentials" exception

Tags: c#, winforms, youtube-api, gdata-api

I am trying to upload a video to youtube using C# Winform and I always get to "Invalid credentials" exception.

1. I am using username and password of my gmail account: is this ok?
2. the application name - can it be anything? or I need register it somewhere?
3. I have created in http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard a developer key, do I need to do more activation in order to make this code work?

This is my code:

```
YouTubeRequestSettings settings;
        YouTubeRequest request;
        string devkey = "My DEV KEY";
        string username = "MY GAMIL MAIL";
        string password = "MY GAMIL PASSWORD";
        settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("SOME APPLICATION", devkey, username, password) { Timeout = -1 };
        request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

        Video newVideo = new Video();

        newVideo.Title = Title;
        newVideo.Description = Description;
        newVideo.Private = true;
        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;



        newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(FilePath, "video/mp4");
        Video createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);

        return createdVideo.VideoId;
```

Answer (score 0):

[That overload](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r890/docs/folder56/M_Google_YouTube_YouTubeRequestSettings__ctor_1.htm) takes an auth token, not a username and password.

If you want to hard-code your password (which is a terrible idea), you also need to [pass a client name](http://google-gdata.googlecode.com/svn-history/r890/docs/folder56/M_Google_YouTube_YouTubeRequestSettings__ctor_2.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I have found this example that has very detailed steps to achieve upload to youtube and many other things in C#

**http://www.cstruter.com/blog/313**

Hope it helpts